# Intel CPU Cannot go deeper than Package C3 state in low power suspend (causing battery drain)

Tags: suspend, dell, power-management, battery, acpi

After digging and searching the whole web, starting with the issue regarding to battery drain while Dell XPS is in suspend to idle (s2idle, S0, S0ix, Modern Standby). This issue is persisting in Windows, Ubuntu and Fedora, Where CPU C-state goes down to C7%, but Package never goes deeper than C3, which is causing Huge battery drain (current power drain is ~5W/h, which is crazy)

After getting more information from Linux OSes, the misleading information I'm getting is related to the Package C states. Which current_driver is shown as intel_idle, but states are named after Cx_ACPI and not having actual intel_idle driver names (C1, C2, ... C10), ACPI states names are only displaying up to C3_ACPI as can be shown below:

```
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state*/name
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0/name:POLL
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1/name:C1_ACPI
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2/name:C2_ACPI
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3/name:C3_ACPI
$ cat /sys/kernel/debug/pmc_core/package_cstate_show
Package C2 : 84450916
Package C3 : 496526337
Package C6 : 0
Package C7 : 0
Package C8 : 0
Package C9 : 0
Package C10 : 0
```

current_drivers shows intel_idle driver:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuidle/current_driver
intel_idle
```

Most threads and places I searched this is how it is supposed to output:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0/name:POLL
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1/name:C1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2/name:C1E
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3/name:C3
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state4/name:C6
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state5/name:C7s
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state6/name:C8
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state7/name:C9
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state8/name:C10
```

My believe is that if I'm able to solve this ACPI idle states to actual intel drivers, S0 will work properly.

Is there anyone having the same issue or already got this resolved?

BTW this is a DELL XPS 9510 i7 11800H 3050Ti

Answer (score 1):

This question comes up often, and I do not think anything is actually wrong, nor is this the source of excessive power consumption.

For Intel processors, the idle state names are the default ACPI related or the more detailed Intel names as a function of if Intel has defined that particular processor to use them or not in the kernel source tree file `drivers/idle/intel_idle.c`. Here is the code fragment:

```
static const struct x86_cpu_id intel_idle_ids[] __initconst = {
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(NEHALEM_EP,          &idle_cpu_nhx),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(NEHALEM,             &idle_cpu_nehalem),
        ...
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(ATOM_AIRMONT,        &idle_cpu_cht),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(IVYBRIDGE,           &idle_cpu_ivb),
        ...
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(SKYLAKE_L,           &idle_cpu_skl),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(SKYLAKE,             &idle_cpu_skl),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(KABYLAKE_L,          &idle_cpu_skl),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(KABYLAKE,            &idle_cpu_skl),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(SKYLAKE_X,           &idle_cpu_skx),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(ICELAKE_X,           &idle_cpu_icx),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(ICELAKE_D,           &idle_cpu_icx),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(ALDERLAKE,           &idle_cpu_adl),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(ALDERLAKE_L,         &idle_cpu_adl_l),
        ...
```

Some processors are not in that list, "Comet Lake" and "Tiger Lake" for example.
One has to look at the `desc` field to gain further insight into the mapping to actual idle states. For example (a Comet Lake processor):

```
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state*/desc
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0/desc:CPUIDLE CORE POLL IDLE
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1/desc:ACPI FFH MWAIT 0x0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2/desc:ACPI FFH MWAIT 0x30
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3/desc:ACPI FFH MWAIT 0x60
```

If the kernel is re-compiled with this patch:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/drivers/idle/intel_idle.c b/drivers/idle/intel_idle.c
index bcf1198e8991..54259172f6fe 100644
--- a/drivers/idle/intel_idle.c
+++ b/drivers/idle/intel_idle.c
@@ -1522,6 +1522,7 @@ static const struct x86_cpu_id intel_idle_ids[] __initconst = {
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(BROADWELL_D,         &idle_cpu_bdx),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(SKYLAKE_L,           &idle_cpu_skl),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(SKYLAKE,             &idle_cpu_skl),
+       X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(COMETLAKE,           &idle_cpu_skl),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(KABYLAKE_L,          &idle_cpu_skl),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(KABYLAKE,            &idle_cpu_skl),
        X86_MATCH_INTEL_FAM6_MODEL(SKYLAKE_X,           &idle_cpu_skx),
```

Then we get this:

```
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state*/desc
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0/desc:CPUIDLE CORE POLL IDLE
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1/desc:MWAIT 0x00
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2/desc:MWAIT 0x01
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3/desc:MWAIT 0x10
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state4/desc:MWAIT 0x20
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state5/desc:MWAIT 0x33
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state6/desc:MWAIT 0x40
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state7/desc:MWAIT 0x50
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state8/desc:MWAIT 0x60
$ grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state*/name
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state0/name:POLL
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state1/name:C1
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state2/name:C1E
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state3/name:C3
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state4/name:C6
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state5/name:C7s
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state6/name:C8
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state7/name:C9
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state8/name:C10
```

The deepest idle state is just as deep, and the idle processor power is similar:

```
doug@s19:~$ sudo turbostat --quiet --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 60
[sudo] password for doug:
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt
0.01    1095    1826    39      2.05    1.32    0.00    1.34
0.02    800     1639    39      1.99    1.28    0.00    1.34
0.05    3393    2746    38      2.05    1.39    0.00    1.33
0.04    2972    2305    39      2.06    1.41    0.00    1.33
0.05    3325    2828    39      2.06    1.41    0.00    1.33
```

For reference, the original kernel:

```
$ sudo turbostat --quiet --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,IRQ,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,CorWatt --interval 60
Busy%   Bzy_MHz IRQ     PkgTmp  PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt
0.03    3233    2345    37      2.17    1.51    0.00    1.33
0.04    3277    2680    37      2.02    1.37    0.00    1.33
0.04    3324    2695    37      2.07    1.41    0.00    1.33
0.04    3151    2706    37      2.03    1.37    0.00    1.33
0.03    3018    2251    37      1.96    1.30    0.00    1.33
0.04    3111    2878    37      2.01    1.36    0.00    1.33
```

EDIT: From the comments it seems the processor only has an idle depth of `MWAIT 0x20` available. Reproducing that on my test server via disabling deeper idle states, still does not increase processor package power by a detectable amount:

```
root@s19:/home/doug# /home/doug/kernel/linux/tools/power/x86/turbostat/turbostat --quiet --Summary --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgWatt,PkgTmp,RAMWatt,GFXWatt,POLL%,C1%,C1E%,C3%,C6%,C7s%,C8%,C9%,C10%,CorWatt --interval 60
Busy%   Bzy_MHz POLL%   C1%     C1E%    C3%     C6%     C7s%    C8%     C9%     C10%    PkgTmp  PkgWatt CorWatt GFXWatt RAMWatt
0.04    3157    0.00    0.01    3.02    0.26    96.67   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    37      2.03    1.37    0.00    1.33
0.05    3425    0.00    0.01    5.48    0.23    94.22   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    37      2.13    1.47    0.00    1.33
0.05    3354    0.00    0.01    6.02    0.27    93.65   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    37      2.07    1.41    0.00    1.33
0.05    3412    0.00    0.01    1.70    0.61    97.63   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    37      2.06    1.41    0.00    1.33
0.05    3569    0.00    0.01    2.69    0.39    96.86   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    37      2.11    1.45    0.00    1.33
```

Comment: I did follow those instructions and added TIGERLAKE and TIGERLAKE_L, but still not reaching PC10 nor PC6. But C1_ACPI was renamed to C1, C2_ACPI is now remaned to C1E, C3_ACPI is renamed to C6. And desc are consecutively MWAIT 0x00 MWAIT 0x01 MWAIT 0x20. It still does NOT show C10. No power improvements was noticed.

Comment: Yes, exactly as expected. There is some other reason your "idle" power is not as low as you expect.

Comment: Oh!! Rereading your comment it sounds as though your deepest idle state is `MWAIT 0x20`, which is not very deep. I disabled deeper idle states on my test server, and still did not observe a measurable increase in processor package power. Are deep idle states disabled in BIOS on your system?

Comment: Right, but I don't have any explicit settings in BIOS regarding this being disabled. I'm using a laptop DELL XPS 15 and laptop BIOS are already very scarce in options. Do you know any non-obvious named options for this purpose?